# Angular JS Array not displaying on html while binding - How to debug issues if no error is shown

Tags: angularjs

I have a simple html and script.js which is using angular js, I am trying to display an array using binding in angular js using ng-repeat, when I refresh my html I am not able to see anything, How do i debug such issues in angular JS when there is no error message on console.

my code

html file

```
<html ng-app="myModule">
<head>
    <!-- Compressed version of angular js below -->
    <!-- <script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script> -->

    <!-- Uncompressed version of angular js below -->
    <script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>  
    <script src="Scripts/Script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <div ng-controller="myController">

        <!-- 2 request are made to the server for image SRC 
            1st request = as soon as the DOM is parsed and binding expression is not evaluated. 
            2nd request = after the binding expression is evaluated, the image is loaded. 

        using ng-src ensures that a request is issued only after angular js has evaluated the binding expression. 

        -->

        <!-- <img ng-src="{{ country.flag }}" atl="{{ country.name + 'Flag'}}" style="height:100px; width:200px"/> -->

    </div>

    <br>
    <div ng-controller="myController">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                    <th>Gender</th>
                    <th>Salary</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="employee in employees">
                    <td>{{ employee.firstName }} </td>
                    <td>{{ employee.lastName }} </td>
                    <td>{{ employee.gender }} </td>
                    <td>{{ employee.salary }} </td>
                </tr>   
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

</body>
</html>

Script.js file 

var myApp = angular
                  .module("myModule",[])
                  .controller("myController", function($scope){

                            var employees = [{ firstName : "David", lastName : "Hastings", gender : "Male", salary : "55500"},
                                            { firstName : "John", lastName : "Hastings", gender : "Male", salary : "45000"},
                                            { firstName : "Mary", lastName : "Hastings", gender : "Female", salary : "90000"},
                                            { firstName : "Sara", lastName : "Hastings", gender : "Female", salary : "89000"},];

                        //$scope.message = "Angular JS Tutorial ";
                        $scope.employee = employees; 

                        /*var country = {
                            name : "USA",
                            capitol : "Washington D.C.", 
                            flag : "./images/image.png"
                        };
                        $scope.country = country;
                        */
                        //$scope.message = "Angular JS Tutorial ";
                        //$scope.message = "Hello Angular!";
                    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `ng-repeat` attribute reads as follows: `employee in employees`, yet in your JS controller you are setting `$scope.employee`.

**As for debugging**, what I usually like to do is console.log the $scope element to console to ensure it is set, if there is something printed that I expected and can't see it in my controller, I'm probably not binding correctly (or in your case, to a plural name of your variable).

Comment: but i my case $scope was set and had no problems but my html had a typo mistake ....so how do i debug such issues in browser ? any suggestions

Comment: @Max When you have logged the scope to the console you can cross reference the items of $scope with your html template, which usually is a case of why somethings isn't binding right - your template.

Comment: ok...thanks Michael, I was expecting an error when the binding value doesn't exists....

Answer (score 1):

Convert this

```
 <tr ng-repeat="employee in employees">
```

to this

```
 <tr ng-repeat="employee in employee">
```

Your assined variable name is `employee`

```
 $scope.employee = employees;
```

Comment: That worked thanks, but how do i debug such issues in angular ? when no error is shown, someone could actually do a typo and sit hours long to figure out such issues ? , please suggest.

Comment: Well,To avoid this kinda error, There are no algorithm to mention. You just have to aware of your code and you have to make your basic strong about angularjs @Max